# Extracting latitude, longitude and altitude using C++ NMEAParser

Tags: python, c++, gps, raspberry-pi4, nmea

I am currently working on a project to calculate the true bearing of a particular object.

So far I have been able to

1. calculate the magnetic declination using a C++ library and code, by manually plugging in the latitude and longitude values.
2. extract latitude, longitude and altitude from a GPS module using a python library and script

But, now I need to feed the GPS live data to the declination calculation function in order to calculate the live declination.

And since the declination calculation is based on a C++ library, I need to transform that python script into a C++ code.

Library details:

1. used pynmea2 library to parse GPS data in the python script

https://pypi.org/project/pynmea2/

2. came across C++ NMEAParser library

https://sourceforge.net/projects/cppnmeaparser/files/latest/download

I am not sure on how to use the C++ NMEAParser in order to get the above mentioned metrics.

Any help regarding how to use this library or what alternative options are there in order to achieve the same function would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Becauseof the simplicity of parsing NMEA data, you may look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515104/parsing-text-and-output-time-of-appearance-of-some-lines/59521558#59521558 and find some good old hand written code.

Comment: thanks!  I'll look into it @ArminMontigny